# Information about System.getProperty("eclipse.commands") to assert if JUnits tests are being run as a plug-in JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, swt

I have a function in my JUnit test class **ValidateConfig.java** which asserts if the test is being run as a plug-in JUnit (function has been mentioned below) and throws an **IllegatStateException** if it is not. I would like to know how this works, what does the parameter in the call to **getProperty** method mean? I tried researching but could not find any satisfying answer Please let me know your suggestions.

```
private void validate() {
if (System.getProperty("eclipse.commands") == null) {
throw new IllegalStateException("Test must be run as a Plug-in JUnit.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a system property which is guaranteed to be set by Eclipse during startup and which is unlikely to be set in a JVM which is not running Eclipse.

The [runtime options help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) details the properties set by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You could list all the current system properties and check the details:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        p.list(System.out);
    }
}
```

You could set the properties in program `System.setProperty("eclipse.commands", "test");` or JVM argument -Dkey=value.